# How to set custom position for array elements on android

Tags: android, android-listview

On this activity :

```
public class ListfileActivity extends Activity {

public int MainId;
private ListView lv;
private ArrayList<String> listview_array = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    // Read page from DB
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
    List<Item> items = db.getAllItemCid();   

    // Add to array
    for (Item cn : items) {
        listview_array.add("ID : " + cn.getId() + " Title : " + cn.getTitle());
    }

    // Make list view
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listview_array));
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
            Intent item = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ItemfileActivity.class);
            item.putExtra("id", arg2);
            startActivity(item);
        }
    });
}
}
```

I get all needed date by db.getAllItemCid() from database, And make listview whit data's, The problem is I need to add array element position on thos part :

```
for (Item cn : items) {
        listview_array.add("ID : " + cn.getId() + " Title : " + cn.getTitle());
}
```

I want add each row id as position ( this is my row id for each row : getId() ) and select position on onItemClick part. as extra : item.putExtra("id", arg2);

and send id ( position ) to next activity.

This code work will, Just I need set position as id , now it set from 0 to ... , I want add each row id as position.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the following code snippet. The fourth parameter itself returns the position of the selected item.

lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int id, **long position**) {
            Intent item = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ItemfileActivity.class);
            item.putExtra("id", id);
            startActivity(item);
        }
    });